# Does combining random and current time decrease probability of collision in this case?

Tags: random, numbers, probability, bit

Lets say we have 2 programs constantly generating random 53 bit numbers. First 32 bits are just system random and last 21 bits are the last bits of current timestamp. The programs probably don't have the same current timestamp, but also the generated numbers aren't compared at the time of generation. Does adding timestamp decrease probability of collision?

```
00000000000000000000000000000000 000000000000000000000  
random                           timestamp
```

Comment: Current timestamp using what precision? Seconds? Milliseconds, Microseconds? Years? Or course it decreases the probability of collision; if the timestamps never collide even by 100% (assuming that the algorithm doesn't run indefinitely, of course). In general however such synchronization cannot be proven to take place and you are better off just filling 53 bytes with random bits.

Comment: Are you aware of sites such as [security.se]? That's probably better suited for these kind of questions. It's probably not suited for [crypto.se] as it currently stands.

Comment: Thank you for help. It would be milliseconds. Information Security or Cryptography? Nothing like that. The purpose of this is network state synchronization.

Comment: Alright. As there is an answer now given, please remind yourself that due to the birthday problem the chance of a collision is about 1 out of 2^(n / 2) for n / 2 invocations. That's why e.g. a random UUID contains 122 bits or so (6 bits out of 128 are used for indicating that it is otherwise randomized and such). 53 bits is really somewhat too small.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes The formula seems a bit strange. Quote: *"chance of a collision is about 1 out of 2^(n / 2) for n / 2 invocations"*. This sounds like for n invocations collisions would have the probability 1 out of 2^n, which is smaller even though there are twice as  many items as before. That cannot be right. Isn't the [probability of having at least one collision 1-e^-(i²/(2b)) for i items and b buckets](https://kevingal.com/blog/collisions.html)?

Comment: Either way, whether 54 bits are sufficient depends on the application: 32-bits of randomness might be a bit risky in most cases. With 32 bits we have b=2^32 buckets. If we generate 10'000 items, there is a 2% chance for collisions. 25k items =>14%. 50k items => 44%. 75k items => 73%. 100k items => 90%. But for 53 bits and 1M (!) items we only have 0.01%. If OP only generates very few numbers (i.e. *way* less than 1M) for a non-critical application, 53 bit should be fine.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a precise calculation for the birthday bound. But for n invocations you can be sure that the probability to choose the same value more than once is dang near 1. 0.01% is not a small chance for one singular part of an application. Again, there is a good reason why we normally use more bits than that.

Comment: I wish I could understand everything that's been said. I guess the conclusions must suffice. It is a non critical application and there is a specific window of time in which the collision can make an impact - the time between the generation and information exchange which most of the times will be almost instantaneous. I must say that this topic is quite interesting, because it turned out to be a battle with percents :) Now on to figuring out the system of court and trial for collisions.

Comment: @kosmo Above discussion might be somewhat irrelevant for your usecase. When you design something like `git`you want your collision chance to be 0% because collisions would break your system. `git`'s design only admits collisions, since they are less likely than hardware fails. But protocols can be designed to work with just one bit of randomness by trying over and over again until it works out eventually. Of course it will take longer with less randomness. So you should compute something like the excepted time and a max. time for 99.99999% of cases to estimate whether 53 bits are sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Appending** the timestamp to a 32 bit random number *can never* lead to more collisions. In the worst case, the timestamp part will always be the same and the chance of collisions stays as high/low as before.

But **overwriting** 21 out of 53 bits (= 40%) of random data with something like a timestamp *can* drastically increase the collision chance. Whether that is relevant or not depends on ...

1. Timestamp resolution
2. Overall runtime of your systems
3. Generation frequency and distribution (!) of the "random" numbers in time
4. Clock synchronization of the systems

Using pure random data without incorporating time will result in an equal or lower collision chance, unless the timestamps are so coarse and the clocks are so out of sync, that the timestamps rarely overlap. But in that case you are effectively using the time part not as time, but as a fingerprint unique to the system. For something like that there are better approaches. Here are some examples, even though none of them are perfect:

- MAC addresses
- Process ID of the program
- Boot time / program start time with nano-second precision

Using fingerprints like these is a gamble. Overall, it can decrease the probability of collisions. But in the case of a fingerprint collision (even if it happens very rarely), the collision chance is drastically higher as long as the fingerprints stay that way. Therefore, I'd recommend to use only randomness. It is easier to implement and collision probabilities are evenly distribute across all cases, no matter under what circumstances your systems run.

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you. I really thought there could be something in it.